# JQuery: RangeError maximum call stack exceeded

Tags: jquery, events, onchange

I have an on change event that fires when a select box is changed. The select box, however, is located inside a div that is replaced and thus the select box is regenerated. Since this error can result from an endless loop, I'm guessing my trigger event must also fire when the select box is created. I have tried many things with no success.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this event from triggering on creation and only when the portion is manually changed?

This is the original code without any attempts to remove the hook or resolve the problem.

```
jQuery('#primary-div .options_box').on( 'change', 'select', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // prevent user from changing again until this process is complete
    jQuery('#primary-div').block({ message: null, overlayCSS: { background: '#f1f1f1', backgroundSize: '32px 32px', opacity: 0.6 } });

    var sel_type = jQuery('#chart_type');
    var sel_month = jQuery('#chart_month');
    var sel_year = jQuery('#chart_year');

    var data_ap = { action: 'update_primary_div', type: sel_type, month: sel_month, year: sel_year };
    $.post( ajaxurl, data_ap, function( response ) {

        $( '#primary-div' ).html( response );

    });

});
```

## Update

While debugging, I added `console.log()` lines after every line of code and found that the string inside the `post` function never prints out, but everything before `post` does. I even commented out the line of code that replaces the HTML inside the DIV, error still continues. So I am thinking that this is not the cause of an endless loop after all. Any other ideas?

Comment: please post some sample code which causes the error to support your question

Comment: You could also probably use `$.one()` instead of `$.on()`, and re-add the handler on the `$.post()` response.

Comment: I tried $.one() but it did not make a difference. It must start over when the element is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. After finding a helpful article I learned that Stack Errors are more commonly caused by passing an illegal parameter to a function. It was at this point that I realized my mistake. jQuery does not allow you to pass its full variable through to the post function (which was not my intention, I forgot an important piece of code when obtaining the chosen values from my select boxes):

`var sel_type = jQuery('#chart_type').val();
var sel_month = jQuery('#chart_month').val();
var sel_year = jQuery('#chart_year').val();`

Answer (score 0):

Because `.options_box` is in `#primary-div`, when the response is received from the **Ajax call**, the HTML for `#primary-div` is updated, which causes `.options_box` to be modified again ...

Change the **HTML structure** so the selects inside `#primary-div` only change when the user changes them.

Comment: So it's impossible? The first (of three) select boxes changes the options in the following select boxes. I need to manage this div through PHP rather than JS for several reasons: there are WordPress filters involved, translation plugins, plus it's just much easier to do so. So I need to be able to update this box without it hitting an endless loop.